# natsort malfunction with leading character PHP

Tags: php, arrays, natsort

i have a few hundred xhtml files the names of which i push to an array. the naming convention is `p0x.xhtml` where `x` is 1-400. i'm trying to `natsort` the array but the leading `p` seems to be conflicting with the sorting.

as a last resort i can rename the files, but want to avoid that if possible. i'd appreciate if anyone knows of a workaround.

```php
$arr = [
    'p010.xhtml',
    'p08.xhtml',
    'p04.xhtml'
];

print_r($arr);
natsort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => p010.xhtml
    [1] => p08.xhtml
    [2] => p04.xhtml
)
Array
(
    [0] => p010.xhtml
    [2] => p04.xhtml
    [1] => p08.xhtml
)
```

and desired output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => p010.xhtml
    [1] => p08.xhtml
    [2] => p04.xhtml
)
Array
(
    [2] => p04.xhtml
    [1] => p08.xhtml
    [0] => p010.xhtml
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it performs as advertised, just not the way you want.  You can switch to [usort/uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) which allows you to provide your own comparison function, in your case a function that returns the natural order of the string minus the leading p?

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   return strnatcmp ( substr($a,1) , substr($b,1) );
}
```

which is called as

```
usort($arr,'cmp');
```

As pointed out [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616322/ordered-object-array-as-per-3-letter-month-order-in-php), in php 5.3+ this can be rewritten as

```
usort($arr,function($a, $b) {
   return strnatcmp ( substr($a,1) , substr($b,1) );
});
```

Comment: thanks, looks like `usort` is the way to go here. was just trying it out with `return str_replace('p', '', $b);` but your `return strnatcmp ( substr($a,1) , substr($b,1) );` outputs as desired